# Write output to csv using a for loop function in R

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, dataframe, datatable

I have two tables and I want to output them to several files. The table looks like:

```
df1 ---
  Colors
  Red
  Blue
```

and

```
df2 ---
 Colors      Name       Rate
 Red         A          3
 Red         B          5   
 Red         C          6
 Blue        D          2
 Blue        E          8
```

I want to write this data to csv files based on colors. That means file one will contain

```
    Colors      Name       Rate
     Red         A          3
     Red         B          5   
     Red         C          6
```

and file two will contain

```
    Colors      Name       Rate     
     Blue        D          2
     Blue        E          8
```

I've tried

```
output_file <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  if (df1$Colors[i] == df2$Colors[i]){
    output_file[i] <- df2[i]
    write.csv(output_file, paste("Color_", i, ".csv"), row.names = F)
  }
}
```

But are syntax errors and I can't find them! Where are the syntax errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need `df2`

You can use `group_by(...)` and `do(...)`

```
library(tidyverse)
path <- "C:/MyDir/"
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  do(write_tsv(., paste0(path, unique(.$cyl))))
```

Or `split(...)` and `map(..., ...)`

```
mtcars %>%
  split(.$cyl) %>%
  map(., ~write_tsv(.x, paste0(path, unique(.$cyl))))
```

Comment: thank you so much on the code! really appreciate it!